# Can Working Cave feed multiple Dwarves

Tags: caverna

In Caverna, there is a furnishing called the Working Cave with the following text:

> **Every time** you have to feed your Dwarfs at the end of a round
>   (*including the special Feeding phases*), you may feed **exactly one**
>   of them with 1 Wood or 1 Stone or 2 Ore (*instead of Food*).

If I have 1 Wood, 1 Stone, 2 Dwarfs, and this furnishing, can I feed my Dwarfs with the Wood and Stone, or must I use food for one Dwarf and either the Wood or Stone for the other?

Comment: I haven't played this game so I feel like I might be missing something, but... it says "exactly one", right?

Comment: Yes. I was leaning toward only being allowed to feed 1 dwarf, but was wondering if anyone had further information.

Comment: What further information could there be?  How else could you possibly interpret "exactly one"?

Comment: Indeed, that's why I tried to ask if there was something else about the game (in the rules) that made this in any way ambiguous. Since it seems not, posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there is something else in the rules that changes the way you're supposed to read that, it means you can only do this for one Dwarf, not multiple.

It says "...feed your **Dwarfs**..." so it's clearly talking about the process of feeding all of them (more than one), but then says you can only use Wood or Stone for **exactly one** of them. That's just an English language thing, not a game rules thing.